# IOS Storyboard размещение по центру

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, storyboard

Такая проблема в визуальном редакторе размещаю картинку и label по центру, а на виртуальном устройстве все это находится левее центра, вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я хз почему так отображается и как это исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы верстаете для iPhone 8, а симулятор запускаете для iPhone 8 Plus. 
Потому у вас и происходит смещение. 
Для того, чтобы label бы по центру можете выбрать один из вариантов:
1. Убрать autoresizing слева [image: скри 1]
В таком случае, при повороте устройства label может уйти за пределы экрана. (не рекомендуется)
2. Более предпочтительнее, это autolayout Установить центрирование Горизонтально(по X) в контейнере:[image: скрин2]
и установить констрейнт к нижней части: [image: скрин3]
Как результат, на всех устройствах Label будет с отступом 103 пункта от низа экрана, и строго по центру оси Х как в портретной ориентации 
[image: скрин4]

так и при горизонтальной ориентации: [image: Скрин 5]

Answer (score 1):

Autolayout. Необходимо установить constraints чтобы были по центру Х и по центру У. Также установить нужно размеры картинки.